# Hive: subquery on GROUP By

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Need a help for Hive query.

I wrote a Hive query :

```
select to_date(from_unixtime(epoch)) as date, count1 , count2, count3 from table1 where count3=168
```

This gives me result as follows:

```
date       count1     count2     count3
7-15-2015  168        3           7
7-15-2015  168        1           5
7-15-2015  168        4           3
and similarly for other dates
```

....

Finally i need to write a query which returns me, median value of count2 and count3 for each date. 
for ex: I need output as:

```
date       count1     count2     count3
7-15-2015  168        3           5
and similarly for other dates
```

I know i need to use group by date and then write subquery on that. 
But I am not able to write correct query. 
Can anyone help me in this

Answer (score 0):

The median is the 2nd quartile, 5th decile, and 50th percentile.  We can calculate the 50th percentile using percentile function in hive:

```
select to_date(from_unixtime(epoch)) as date
 , count1 
 , percentile(count2,0.5) as median_ct2
 , percentile(count3,0.5) as median_ct3
from table1 
where count1=168
group by to_date(from_unixtime(epoch)), count1;
```

Comment: Did this work as solution for you?  If so can you select as such so the community can benefit.